# MySql database Optimisation with multithreading

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

I need to implement multithreading in Java Springboot. While doing load testing with 10000 requests, I am facing JDBC related issues:

1. JDBC Connection exception – this is resolved by using hikariCP with these configured values:

   ```
    #maximum number of milliseconds that a client will wait for a connection
    spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 5000

    #minimum number of idle connections maintained by HikariCP 
    #in a connection pool
    spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10 

    spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 203
    spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=5000 
    spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1000 
    spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =false
   ```
2. PessimisticLockException – I am facing this with increased thread count (more than 100) and with the Hikari max pool set to 205.

My doubt is with 10000 requests. How can I analyse the optimum performance? What tweaks  are required? (buffer pool, timeouts)

I am using `threadpooltask` executor with values:

```
thread.corepool.size = 50
thread.maxpool.size = 100
```

Also, to increase performance, we have multiple pods running for the same instance.
I saw one blog saying that more database connections slows the performance: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

I am using an AWS RDS 8xlarge instance.

Comment: Are threads created at a relatively steady rate?  Or is it 'bursty'?  What actions do you hope to perform "in parallel"?  You tagged with [mysql], so perhaps SQL?  After about 10 _active_ threads, MySQL starts to stumble over itself.  That is, too large a pool is counterproductive.  (I like a supermarket with people and carts as an anology.)

Comment: @RickJames I dont get the part of threads being bursty. As mentioned with 10k data each threads picks up the request having 8 instances with maximum thread allowed as 100. from database perspective, the connection is about 695. Problem is the whole performance is slow. how to increase db performance ?

Comment: After 10-20 copies of that are running, they all bog down and go slower.  Each gets a fair share of resources, which leads to every copy being slowed down.

Answer (score 0):

After 10-20 copies of that are running, they all bog down and go slower. Each gets a fair share of resources, which leads to every copy being slowed down.

Am mostly anti-benchmarking, unless the queries are thrown at the server are realistic and are run at a realistic rate.  Don't start with 10K threads; instead start with very few and gradually increase until performance falls off a cliff.  *That* will tell you how many you can handle.

Then, if necessary, you must keep from exceeding that many *simultaneous* threads.

That is, 203 is likely to lead to many slow threads.  And, "throughput" may even suffer.  That is 203 all at once may take longer to finish than 203 spread out over some period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am going with 1k requests now, which is smaller as to what i was using. But even then how to optimise database configration ? which formulas or how to analyse or manage these ? i am very new to oracle and monitoring statistics is not helping. anything i could use which could give me better results with multithreading ?

Comment: @ana - "Oracle" is a different product than "MySQL".  (MySQL includes MariaDB, Aurora, Percona, RDS, and a few others.)

Comment: @ana - But what is the goal?  "Maximizing number of threads?"  I doubt it.  "Maximizing number of tasks finished per hour?"  That requires finding the sweet spot; it is likely to be below 100 threads running "simultaneously".  All the curves I have seen show near-linear growth until a few dozen, then flatten off ore even drop.

Comment: oh, i see, so in that case with the referred link in description, how could i ensure that i am using mysql with multi threading approach in the most optimal way ?

Comment: Goal is to improve my performance, using multi threading approach. but it seems like with some connections and all, the whole process is slowed down.  i dont know wether increasing threads or decreasing connections, or implying indexes would help.

Comment: @ana - I read some of that link.  A lot of the principles in it are similar to what I am saying.  Also, notice the red line on the chart and how it flattens out after 36 clients.  The curve looks the same with MySQL; the "36" varies with version and type of benchmark.  After "36" the "tasks completed per hour" does not change as you change "number of clients".

Comment: Another way to look at it...  Once you have saturated all the cores and/or the disk subsystem and/or the network, you can't work any faster.  (And, due to added contention, things might slowdown.)